# Replace UIImagePicker view

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to replicate the Camera app by using custom overlay views. I need to show the gallery when the user clicks a button from inside a custom toolbar. 
Is there a way to replace the camera view with the gallery view? At first glance I tried to dismiss the UIImagePickerController and then configure it again to show the gallery... but that's not the desired effect. Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just set the `sourceType` property of your `UIImagePickerController` object to `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary` - that will change what your image picker displays.

[`sourceType` API documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007070-CH3-SW5)